# Grails hasOne and hasMany same domain

Tags: grails, has-many, has-one

I have domain like this:

```
class Team {
 hasOne [leader: Person]
 hasMany [member: Person]
}

class Person {
 belongsTo [team: Team]
}
```

But when the tables are generated, there is not a column like leader_id in the team table. And thus the leader relation is not persisted.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that, what I need is

```
class Team {
 belongsTo [leader: Person]
 hasMany [member: Person]
}

class Person {
 belongsTo [team: Team]
}
```

so that the Team table can have the desired "leader" reference back to Person.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html):

Use a hasOne association to store the foreign key reference in child table instead of the parent in a bidirectional one-to-one.

You're child table here is Person and your parent is Team. Grails is working as expected.

Comment: Right, so the OP should keep the `hasMany` to member but should change the `leader` to be just `Person leader`